# Stringbuilder used in Parallel.Foreach loop

Tags: .net-4.0, thread-safety, task-parallel-library, .net-4.5, parallel.foreach

In my code, there is a `foreach` loop that iterates through all items in a collection and appends text inside a `StringBuilder` to create a ".ics" file. To make this faster I converted foreach loop to `Parallel.Foreach` loop. Though the performance was improved, the text in ".ics" file was unordered which created a corrupted file.

Example of expected text in ".ics" file =>

```
Begin:calendar
Begin:event1
.
.
End:event1
Begin:event2
.
.
End:event2
End:Calendar
```

Example of ".ics" file created by using parallel.foreach loop =>

```
Begin:calendar
Begin:event1
Begin:event2
.
.
.
.
End:Event1
End:Event2
```

Is there a way to create a unique `StringBuilder` for each item in collection and then join them at the end of loop to create an ordered string?

Answer (score 0):

I added a new StringBuilder variable inside "Parallel.Foreach" loop and at the end of the loop the contents of new StringBuilder variable is appended with the main Stringbuilder variable.
By creating a new Stringbuilder variable inside the loop, it acts as a private object for each thread running in parallel.